# dojo array.push replaced the previous item

Tags: javascript, arrays, dojo, push

the following javascript returns `personNames` as

`[{"name":"smith"},{"name":"smith"},{"name":"smith"}]`

instead of

`[{"name":"john"},{"name":"doug"},{"name":"smith"}]`

```js
var personNames = []; 
var personName = {}; 

var persons = [{"firstname": "john", "id": "111"}, {"firstname": "doug", "id": "777"}, {"firstname": "smith", "id": "888"}];

if(persons.length > 0){
  array.forEach(persons, function(person){
  personName.name = person.firstname;
  personNames.push(personName);
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to create a new object in the `forEach` function. Currently you are reusing the same `personName` object.

Comment: thank you. after i moved the var personName={}; within the forEach loop, it worked.

Comment: your code doesnt even run as is (in a browser anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  array.forEach(persons, function(person){
  personName.name = person.firstname;
  personNames.push(personName);
  });
```

`personName` refers to the same object in each iteration. JavaScript keeps a reference to that object in memory, so when you update it later on, it updates everywhere, including inside the array.

For your use-case, you need to re-initialize `personName` each time:

```
  array.forEach(persons, function(person){
  personName = {};
  personName.name = person.firstname;
  personNames.push(personName);
  });
```

(Is the first line supposed to be `persons.forEach(function(person){`?)

Comment: i use dojo/_base/array. so the syntax is corret

Answer (score 1):

First as a way to grab names you can use `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
var persons = [{"firstname": "john", "id": "111"}, {"firstname": "doug", "id": "777"}, {"firstname": "smith", "id": "888"}];

var personNames = persons.map(p => ({ name: p.firstname }));

console.log(personNames);
```

**Then** the problem with your code is that you created an object and every time you change the value of that and then push the same object to array again.

I think you forget some thing about objects and referencing. BTW this would be the correct implementation of yours:

```js
var persons = [{"firstname": "john", "id": "111"}, {"firstname": "doug", "id": "777"}, {"firstname": "smith", "id": "888"}];

var personNames = [];

persons.forEach(p => personNames.push({ name: p.firstname }));

console.log(personNames);
```

**Another thing to mention** is that there is no need to check if there is any items in persons.

Answer (score 0):

Just use personName localy like that :

```
var personNames = [];

var persons = [{"firstname": "john", "id": "111"}, {"firstname": "doug", "id": "777"}, {"firstname": "smith", "id": "888"}];

if(persons.length > 0) {
    persons.forEach(element => {
      var personName = {};
      personName.name = element.firstname;
      personNames.push(personName);
    });
}
console.log(personNames); // [ { name: 'john' }, { name: 'doug' }, { name: 'smith' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

- `$array.forEach()` is not a function because `array` is not defined.
  Use name of the array instead i.e `persons.forEach()`.
- Use `personName` locally else you will be accessing the global instance of the variable which will return the last updated value.
  [Check code snippet at JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sorafaroga/edit?js,console,output)

```js
   

 var personNames = []; 

var persons = [{"firstname": "john", "id": "111"}, {"firstname": "doug", "id": "777"}, {"firstname": "smith", "id": "888"}];

if(persons.length > 0){
  persons.forEach(function(person){
    //use personName locally
    var personName = {};
    personName.name = person.firstname;

    personNames.push(personName);
  });
}

console.log(personNames);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that

```
var personNames = []; 

var persons = [{"firstname": "john", "id": "111"}, {"firstname": "doug", "id": "777"}, {"firstname": "smith", "id": "888"}];
for (i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
   personNames.push({name:persons[i].firstname});
}
```